# How does flask's app pattern works?

Tags: python, flask

I'm willing to understand how Flask's internal app pattern works. I'm not talking about blueprints.

Flask is working differently from eg. Django because you can instanciate any number of apps and give them config.

I'm wondering how Flask's handles config. How does it pass this object to all the parts of the app.

I'm wondering about that because I want to refactor the config of my application to follow this pattern, so I need to understand it.

Edit: I don't have any problem with the Config. I'm just trying to replicate the pattern used in Flask.

Thanks,

Alexis.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask `app.config` is a dictionary. You can put your configuration data there. That's it.

Wherever you import of reference `app` it will come with it's `config` attribute which you can access.